# Simulate touches on iOS 7 (not inside my application)

Tags: iphone, ios7, automated-tests, touches

I want to automate touches on iPhone for automate posts in facebook, twitter and phone calls.
In android i used MonkeyRunner and it works perfectly, i can record a session of touches and create also my own predefined scripts. Is there something similar in iOS 7? it's not something that i have to pubblish in app store so i can use and jailbroken phones.

Comment: Try [Appium](http://appium.io/). Appium is an open source test automation framework for use with native and hybrid mobile apps. It drives iOS and Android apps using the WebDriver JSON wire protocol.

Comment: Appium is a great test tool but i think is not what i am looking for. Reading some documentation it says: Support for automating vendor-provided or third-party apps: Only vendor-provided apps (Preferences, Maps, etc…), and only on the simulator.I need to test in real devices.

Comment: Hey, did you end up finding anything in regards to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to do it through `Instruments`, there's a UI Testing interface that uses JavaScript to control an app.

[Automating UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)

Comment: Automating UI Testing works only for testing of my own application. I need something tha operates touches outside of my application. For example go to home page -> open facebook -> post something.